# Glitches when trying to updating the "gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons"

Tags: interface, drag-and-drop

So, a new version of "gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons" has came out with features that i want, like being able to drag files with your mouse into your browser. But when i've installed the extention, they kept switching from one to the other, and i can't unninstall the old one from the site. Does someone knows how to replace the old one completely?

Old:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/
New:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/

Comment: Have you tried reporting the issue to the author for advice?

Comment: Yeah, i found his email, but this is Ubuntu's default extention, how do i contact the developers to inform them?